# Instruments Time Profiler changes to CPU Usages

Tags: xcode, cpu-usage, instruments

I'm trying to use the Time Profiler instrument in Instruments. 
Every time I press the Record button the Time Profiler changes to CPU Usage.

And I really need the Time Profiler instrument.

What is going wrong?

*Running Xcode 7.1 (7B91b)*

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time Profiler` is the name of the *Template*, where as `CPU Usage` is the name of the *Instrument*.

Some templates are configured with multiple instruments. For example, `Energy Diagnostics` contains the instruments `Energy Usage`, `CPU Activity`, and `Network Activity`. Some instruments break down into multiple rows of reporting when you start recording, such as the `VM Tracker` instrument (from the `Allocations` template), which shows `Dirty Size` and `Resident Size`.